# Query Posts by date range with fixed beginning and end

Tags: wp-query, query-posts, query, date

I need to get posts from a certain timeframe.
I am using the `posts_where` filter.

I want to specify a beginning date and an end date.
This is the function I use:

```
function filter_where( $where = '' ) {
    $where .= " AND post_date >= '2012-03-01' AND post_date =< '2014-03-01'";
    return $where;
}
```

This Filter returns nothing. The error ust be located anywhere around the second `AND`.

This is my function:

```
number_sold_mottos( $from, $till );

function number_sold_mottos( $from, $till ){
    add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
    $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_type' => 'shop_order'  );
    $post_ids   = array();
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    $last_order_ids = array();
    if ( $the_query -> have_posts() ):
        while ( $the_query -> have_posts()) :
            $the_query -> the_post();
            the_title();
        endwhile;
    endif;
    wp_reset_query();
    remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' ); 
}


function filter_where( $where ) {
    $where .= " AND post_date >= '2012-03-01' AND post_date =< '2014-03-01'";
    return $where;
}
```

Any help is welcome.

Comment: could you show the code for your loop too please, are you using query_posts?

Comment: Your only problem was that `=<` operator doen't exists in MySQL, the right operator for 'lower-or-equal-to' is `<=`

Comment: hmm, didn't spot that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably add the filter, then use a new query, then remove the filter.

```
function filter_where( $where ) {
    $where .= " AND post_date >= '2012-03-01' AND post_date <= '2014-03-01'";
    return $where;
}
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );

$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'shop_order' ) );
while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
    the_title();
    the_content();
endwhile;

remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
```

Comment: please have a look at my edit.

Comment: does this code work if you use it in place of your function above?

Answer (score 0):

don't do empty `$where` variable in function argument this is why you are getting nothing, because your `$where` statement defined in your function has not any query parameters other than date range, you need to expand `$where` like this.

EDITED:

```
number_sold_mottos( $from, $till );

function number_sold_mottos( $from, $till ){
     add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
     $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_type' => 'shop_order'  );
     $post_ids   = array();
     $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
     $last_order_ids = array();
     if ( $the_query->have_posts() ):
         while ( $the_query->have_posts()) :
             $the_query->the_post();
             the_title();
         endwhile;
         wp_reset_postdata();
     endif;
    remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' ); 
}


function filter_where( $where ) {
    $where .= " AND post_date >= '2012-03-01' AND post_date <= '2014-03-01'";
    return $where;
}
```

Comment: I tried it your way, but I still do not get any result.

Comment: @user998163 i have edited your code try now.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you:

```
//Add the filter
add_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where' );
//Remove the = ''
function filter_where( $where ) {
    $where .= " AND post_date >= '2012-03-01' AND post_date =< '2014-03-01'";
    return $where;
}
```

You must know also that this filter will affect to all the queries performed in your site except the queries using `get_posts()` function, except if you set the argument `suppress_filters` to false, for example `get_posts( array( 'suppress_filters' => FALSE ) );`

Answer (score 0):

Additional information (no solution before WordPress 3.7): There is [`WP_Date_Query`](http://phpdoc.wordpress.org/trunk/WordPress/WP_Date_Query.html).